# function returning undefined when using

Tags: javascript

i have a function that connect to MsSQL database to get some data and build a text statement , here it's :

```
function getActions(issue_id, callback){
    var action = '';
    var conn2 = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
        if(err){
            showNotification('error connecting for selecting actions for ALL issues: ' + err.message, 'danger', 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks');
        } else {
            var request = new sql.Request(conn2);
            request
            .input('issue_id', sql.Int,issue_id)
            .query('SELECT [date], [description] FROM [actions] WHERE [issue_id] = @issue_id')
            .then(function(data2) {
                action ='<tr>'+
                                '<td style="vertical-align: top;" class="bold">action:</td>'+
                                '<td>'+
                                '<table>';
                data2.forEach(function(data21){
                        action +='<tr>'+
                                    '<td>'+data21.date+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data21.description+'</td>'+
                                    '</tr>';

                });
                action += '</table>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '</tr>'+
                            '</tbody>'+
                            '</table>';
            console.log(action);
            callback(null, action);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            showNotification('Error on selecting actions for ALL issues:' + error.message, 'danger', 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks');
        });

    }

});    
}
```

but when i use the function in another place in my code it return undefined instead of the text statement , i make a console.log(action) before the return statement it it return the correct text ..... i did't get it  why it return undefined when using the function

**UPDATE** when i used the function from Aruna i'm using the function like this:

```
for(let b=0;b<id.length;b++){
    getActions(id[b],function(err, action) {
        arrAction[b] = action;
    });
 }
```

Comment: `getActions` does not return anything.

Comment: the function `getActions` does not return anything, so, yes, it's the same as `return undefined;` - for a function to return anything, you need to `return` something, but as this function contains asynchronous code, you need to either use a callback or return a Promise to be at all useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you connect and query MySQL database asynchronously, you can't expect the data returned synchronously.

You should use 'callback' to handle this.

So your code can be like this,

```
function getActions(issue_id, callback){
var action = '';
var conn2 = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
    if(err){
        showNotification('error connecting for selecting actions for ALL issues: ' + err.message, 'danger', 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks');
    } else {
        var request = new sql.Request(conn2);
        request
        .input('issue_id', sql.Int,issue_id)
        .query('SELECT [date], [description] FROM [actions] WHERE [issue_id] = @issue_id')
        .then(function(data2) {
            action ='<tr>'+
                            '<td style="vertical-align: top;" class="bold">action:</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                            '<table>';
            data2.forEach(function(data21){
                action +='<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+data21.date+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data21.description+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>';

            });
            action += '</table>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '</tr>'+
                            '</tbody>'+
                            '</table>';
            console.log(action);
            callback(null, action);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            showNotification('Error on selecting actions for ALL issues:' + error.message, 'danger', 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks');
        });

    }

});    
}
```

And you should call the same like this,

```
var issue_id = 12;
getActions(issue_id, function(err, action) {
   // to do
});
```

Also, change your for loop like this, as you called asynchronous function inside the loop, the for loop variable "b" will get changed before the response comes from the function

```
var arrAction = [];
for(let b=0;b<id.length;b++){
    getActions(id[b],function(err, action) {
        arrAction[arrAction.length] = action;
    });
 }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with what you tried and how you passed the callback? I will have a look then.

Comment: Sorry, in the function 'getActions', you have to pass the issue_id first then the callback function like, "getActions(issue_id, function(...", something like this. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can have a look at the bottom, and pass "issue_id"

Comment: Can you update the function you tried as well in the question?

Comment: Also, I have updated the for loop in the bottom of the answer which you have to change.

Comment: Can you change the for loop as I suggested and try again?

Comment: Also check, are you calling "getActions" from any other place without passing a function

Answer (score 0):

`getActions` does not return anything.

`return action` is called within an inner function, something to do with the `sql.Connection` class. Perhaps you should `return conn2;` at the end of `getActions`? It is hard to say without context on what you are doing.